# merge hashes using + operator

Tags: ruby

Do you see any drawback (besides the obvious ones with monkey patching) in doing this?

```
class Hash
   def +(other)
     self.merge(other)
   end
end
```

I found this really handy, but maybe there's something I'm not considering and could be problematic.

Comment: Patching standard ruby libraries with brand new methods, you should likely never run into problems with ruby core. That’s good. On the other hand, if you rely on 3rd party libs, you have a chance to occasionally get stuck while adding 9001st off-site gem/lib. In such a case you will hardly understand why a mere _3rd-party-n-graph-parser_ fails to work properly. The only case I can imagine, though, is that foreign lib will use `respond_to? :+` to distinguish instances of a huge load of classes instead of giant `case` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any major drawbacks. A very minor drawback is that it adds an extra level to a call stack, making it slightly slower. To avoid this, you can use alias:

```
class Hash
  alias :+ :merge
end
```

A benefit may be that you will be able to use the `+=` syntax sugar, but I cannot think of a use case where you want to use `+=` instead of `merge!`. The difference between them is whether the object id changes.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the implementation to use alias